# Перенос сайта с хостинга на локальный сервер

Tags: php, sql

Есть сайт, cms - Instantcms. Локальный сервер winginx. Сделал бэкап сайта, разархивировал. Сайт не запускается из-за проблем с sql: у меня на локальном сервере нет таких пользователей базы sql, как на хостинге. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: У тя какой сервер стоит ?

Comment: Создать новую бд, залить дамп, переписать конфиг сайта на новое подключение к базе, не?

Answer (score 1):

Запустить установку по-новой.

Answer (score 0):

1. Создать пользователя и БД.
2. Залить базу.
3. Указать пользователя, пароль и БД в конфигах.